# Python Scrapy script works in VSCode debugger, but not when running the script manually

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, scrapy, vscode-debugger

I have a scrapy spider named `google_spider` which I call using the below script:

```
# google.py

import os
from scrapy.cmdline import execute

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

try:
    execute(
        [
            "scrapy",
            "crawl",
            "google_spider",
        ]
    )
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

I run the script using `python google.py` and it used to work as intended.

I can also run it using the VSCode Python debugger.

But now it doesn't work when i use `python google.py`, and instead display the following error:

(It works perfectly fine using the vscode debugger)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aussie/google.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "C:\Users\heybi\Miniconda3\envs\f_leadersystems\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\heybi\Miniconda3\envs\f_leadersystems\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3239, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "C:\Users\heybi\Miniconda3\envs\f_leadersystems\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3222, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\heybi\Miniconda3\envs\f_leadersystems\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3264, in _initialize_master_working_set
    tuple(
  File "C:\Users\heybi\Miniconda3\envs\f_leadersystems\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3265, in <genexpr>
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "C:\Users\heybi\Miniconda3\envs\f_leadersystems\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2780, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "C:\Users\heybi\Miniconda3\envs\f_leadersystems\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2279, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "C:\Users\heybi\Miniconda3\envs\f_leadersystems\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2212, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "C:\Users\heybi\Documents\Code\Projects\Freelancer\scrape leadersystems 27791862\aussie\google.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
ImportError: cannot import name 'execute' from partially initialized module 'scrapy.cmdline' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\heybi\Miniconda3\envs\f_leadersystems\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py)
```

Comment: why does `pkg_resources` want to load your `google.py` as a module

Comment: How did you manually execute "python google.py"? Have you switched the execution terminal before this?

Comment: @rioV8 I think scrapy is searching for all `.py` files and loading them as modules by default

Comment: @JillCheng I used the bash terminal in vscode to run it mnually, when I start debugger on vscode, it opens a new debugger console terminal to execute the script. So yeah it's different terminals.

Comment: @Biswajit Chopdar -According to "most likely due to a circular import", please check whether there is a circular import in the file and whether there is a renaming of the file name and the module name.